# Android - flavor version naming

Tags: android, android-flavors

I'm developing a white label application. the application have many flavors, each flavor is for different client. All flavors are shearing the core logic and difference between them is mostly in design.
the question is what is the best practice for naming the versions and tracking features update?

for example, let's say I release 1.0.0 version for two clients. after the release the first client request a lot of updates and we got with him to version 1.2.6 (and let's say that most of the updates was in core logic).
and after that, the second client is requesting some small update, like moving the logo or something. so should I increase his version to 1.0.1, or make it same as first client version?
because in his new release he will have all the new core features that got in first client's 1.2.6 version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to use major version for core updates, and minor - for custom updates. So for example, use 2 first numbers in version for core updates - first for major core updates, second - for minor core updates. 3rd - major client custom updates, 4th - minor client custom updates.

So if you have core version of 1.2, then final version will look like 1.2.1.1